# version `GLIBC_2.7' not found when import pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have downloaded torch-0.1.12.post2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl(from http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu75/torch-0.1.12.post2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl ) file and use the following command to install.

```
pip install torch-0.1.12.post2-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
pip install pip install torchvision
```

However, the error occurs when import torch

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/my/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: /lib64/tls/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /home/my/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/lib/libTH.so.1)
```

My Linux kernel is 2.6.32_1-19-0-0 and GCC version is 4.8.3

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You should try compiling pytorch from source. The distributed version seems to be compiled using a newer linux distribution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about installation. It is not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

What's the output of running `/lib64/tls/libc.so.6`?

PyTorch requires glibc version 2.7 or newer. You may need to update your glibc version.

Comment: He's probably using redhat 6 or cetos 6 which means upgrading glibc may not be straight forward.